# MYSQL - How to run a query where the values of one condition match the value of another?

Tags: mysql, sql, popsql

It would be something where you could select eye_color, hair_color, sex...from a table of characteristics and if every value of eye_color(e.g, 'Dark brown') = every hair_color('Dark brown') then you run the query.

Comment: yes it is possible, even if you need to use a stored procidure, but please add more information else it is hard to tell one way like this `
SELECT a.* FROm a WHERE a.xoy = 1 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM characteristics WHERE eye_color = "Dark brown" AND  hair_color = "Dark brown"`

Comment: *AND IF every VALUE of eye_color(Dark brown) = every hair_color(Dark brown)* ??? This needs in all values to be the same? if there are 2 different values in some mentioned column then opposite column values are equal to NOT EVERY value. Your need is too illogical... demonstrate it on some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution for MySQL:

```
SELECT eye_color=hair_color, sex... 
FROM characteristics
WHERE eye_color=hair_color = '1';
```